# How to determine if I should use a layout view Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have skimmed through all the marionette articles on the layout view and I am not sure if there are advantages to using that versus how I have my app setup now, let me show you.

After building the components to my app I then created an app level view that handles the initialization and rending of all those views.

```
var Backbone   = require('backbone'),
    TeamsView  = require('./teams'),
    DataView   = require('./teamData'),
    LeaderView = require('./leader');

module.exports = appView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#wrap',
    template: require('../../templates/app.hbs'),
    initialize: function() {
        window.App.views.teamsView = new TeamsView({ collection: window.App.data.teams });
        window.App.views.dataView  = new DataView({  collection: window.App.data.teams });
        window.App.views.leaderView = new LeaderView({  collection: window.App.data.teams });
    },
    render: function() {
        var teamsView  = window.App.views.teamsView;
        var dataView   = window.App.views.dataView;
        var leaderView = window.App.views.leaderView;
        this.$el.find('#basketball .app').prepend(teamsView.render().el);
        this.$el.find('#basketball .app').prepend(dataView.render().el);
        this.$el.prepend(leaderView.render().el);
    }
});
```

Then inside a controller I render the app view above.

This feels comfortable to me, but somewhere deep inside says it's wrong and I should be looking at layout views?

So my question more specifically is when putting the pieces together in an backbone application should I be looking into layout views or is creating a single app level view (like above) sufficient?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Region View"... do you mean a Layout View?

Comment: Yeah changing it now..... done!

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is fine at the simplest level, though perhaps more manual than it needs to be.  However, you may want a Layout View as things get more complex.

The value of a Layout View comes when you have a region in your App that you'd like to have contain sub-regions, but only during certain views.  For example, you might have an index/list inside of your App's `#mainRegion` that just has a bunch of teams, in which case you could use a `CollectionView` (or `CompositeView` if you want to add some styling) along with the `ItemView` for each team.

However, say you click to edit one of the teams, and now you want the `#mainRegion` to show the edit page, which itself has some information about the team in `#infoRegion` and then an edit form in a `#formRegion`.  These are regions that are specific to the edit page, and so you'd want to use a Layout View to manage them rather than delegating all the way up to the App level.

I hope this makes sense, and I'm happy to clarify if needed.  You can also check out the documentation for a breakdown of when to use each view type:  https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Use-cases-for-the-different-views

Comment: Thanks for a more personal explanation and example, that's what I was looking for. I know the app will get more complex, I am trying to prepare early. I just don't have time to experiment and find out that layout views are for something else, the name itself makes sense in that I need to layout all the pieces so yeah I need to read as much as I can about it. Thanks